# ybar interval and lines on plot

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

How do I get rid of the vertical lines either side of each bar in this
plot?  I think they appear due to the `ybar interval` command which I
need for the `xticklabel` command.

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{foo.csv}
n,o
46,7
89,10
96,35
100,66
32,60
8,10
43,136
44,154
90,115
88,161
10,145
7,82
8,96
31,88
9,51
6,177
38,174
50,52
32,14
44,50
17,187
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar interval,
    xticklabel=\rotatebox{90}{\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick},
    xtick style={draw=none},
    ymin=0
    ]
\addplot+ [hist={data=x}] table [x=o,col sep=comma] {foo.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `grid=none` to the `axis` options.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\begin{filecontents}{foo.csv}
n,o
46,7
89,10
96,35
100,66
32,60
8,10
43,136
44,154
90,115
88,161
10,145
7,82
8,96
31,88
9,51
6,177
38,174
50,52
32,14
44,50
17,187
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar interval,
        xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick,
        xticklabel style={
            rotate=90,
        },
        xtick style={draw=none},
        ymin=0,
        grid=none,          % <-- added
    ]
        \addplot+ [hist={data=x}] table [x=o,col sep=comma] {foo.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]